# Pseudo variable

Tags: windows, executable, exe, portable-executable

Can someone please explain me what is a Pseudo Variable and what exactly is the first parameter to the function WinMain below??

```
GetStartupInfo(&StartupInfo);
int nMainRetVal = WinMain((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, NULL, pszCommandLineAnsi,
   (StartupInfo.dwFlags & STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW)
      ? StartupInfo.wShowWindow : SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Also what does the following statement do??

```
extern "C" const IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `WinMain` is a so-called "application instance handle". This thing originated from the ancient Windows 3.x times, where it denoted the handle to the running instance of the application. But starting from Win32 (Windows 9x/NT) this parameter is the base address of the executable module mapping in the process virtual address space.

So, what you see is the image base address `__ImageBase`, which is cast to `HINSTANCE` to meet the `WinMain` signature.

Now, `__ImageBase` - I guess it's a build-time-generated structure that resides exactly at the image starting address.

And, I'm not certain what is a "Pseudo Variable". But perhaps this is exactly `__ImageBase`.

Answer (score 0):

__ImageBase is the ["current module's HINSTANCE from a static library"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/25/247180.aspx). This is a so called pseudovariable which the linker provides. This pseudovariable is the address where the module has been loaded in memory. Using this pseudovariable you can directly access the mapped image from memory and address its content.